# LINQ expression behaves differently on literals?

Tags: c#, linq

in a different SO question it was asked to get a signed integer reversed digit-wise:
123 becomes 321 and -123 becomes -321

this is an obvious, quite readable implementation:

```
int reverse (int i) {
    int sign = i/Math.Abs(i);
    var abs = string.Concat(Math.Abs(i).ToString().Reverse());
    return int.Parse(abs)*sign;
}
```

this more compact LINQ expression was also suggested:  `.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0');`

but I do not understand the results of the latter:

```
int j = -123;

int a =  j.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0');
int b = -(123.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0'));
int c = -123.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0');
int d = -(123).ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0');
Console.WriteLine($"{a} , {b} , {c} , {d}");
```

results in

```
3207 , -321 , -321 , -321
```

why does it only work with a literal int?
whats is my fallacy, what do I assume wrongly?

Comment: okay, I'd like to conclude: there is not nice LINQ expression for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `a` you're starting with `-123` but with the others you're starting with `123` and making the result `-`.

### You need to enclose 123 like so `(-123)`

Check it out.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        int j = -123;

        int a = j.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0');
        int b = -(123.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0'));
        int c = -123.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0');
        int d = -(123).ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0');

        //Make -123 like line below.
        int e = (-123).ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0');

        Console.WriteLine($"{a} , {b} , {c} , {d}, {e}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
//OUTPUTS
//3207 , -321 , -321 , -321, 3207
```

---

### Edit

I answered above why you weren't getting the proper results with the method but I did not answer how it could be achieved. For now I concur with you; "there is not nice LINQ expression for this". However; I was able to turn it into a decently readable one line of code that became a beautiful looking extension method.

I did take a look at the comments below the question and I borrowed from Falco Alexander's comment to use `Math.Sign` a feature I didn't know existed honestly.  I was going to do it manually with a `if x < 0 return result * -1` sorta deal.

I also noticed an issue with the current `Aggregate` function being used and that's that it doesn't support decimals.  Currently it's only `int` but I took it up a notch and tried with `double` as well.  To add the decimal point I aggregated a `string`; but then I assumed aggregating a string is a bad thing since we only want to perform string computations as little as possible and just made a `new string` (which breaks the inline LINQ look but performs much better I'm assuming)  Anyway; I ended up with what you see below, almost identical to what you have, but working negatives and decimals.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int j = -123;        
        int k = 123;        
        double l = -123.456;
        double m = 123.456;

        Console.WriteLine(j.Reverse());
        Console.WriteLine(k.Reverse());
        Console.WriteLine(l.Reverse());
        Console.WriteLine(m.Reverse());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static int Reverse(this int value)
    {
        return Math.Sign(value) * int.Parse(new string(Math.Abs(value).ToString().Reverse().ToArray()));
    }

    public static double Reverse(this double value)
    {
        return Math.Sign(value) * double.Parse(new string(Math.Abs(value).ToString().Reverse().ToArray()));
    }
}
//OUTPUTS
//-321
//321
//-654.321
//654.321
```

Comment: pls see my comment at the other answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that in all cases except for `a` the `int` converted to `string` is "123" and not "-123". The minus sign is applied to the result of execution and not used in a `.ToString` call

In this expression:

```
-123.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0')
```

The `.ToString()` will be called on "123" and then the rest of LINQ query is executed with Aggregate returning `int` and only then the minus sign will be applied to resulting int number. An illustration of it would be:

```
-1 * 123.ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(...)
```

Even this expression:

```
int d = -(123).ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0');
```

Will be transformed to something like:

```
int d = -1 * (123).someExpr
```

First compiler removes redundant parentheses, then executes expression and at last it changes the sign of result to minus

P.S.

As @PetSerAI correctly pointed out you could modify LINQ expression to make it work as follows:

```
int d = Math.Sign(j) * Math.Abs(j).ToString().Reverse().Aggregate(0, (y, x) => 10 * y + x - '0')
```

Comment: I answered first with code example and you got the plus one lol.  SO hates me.

Comment: I understand, this means the Aggregate hack is only working with unsigned int and the sign is applied after. how could I make the LINQ expression to work with the int variable to get the correct result?

Comment: So you mean without using ToString()?

Comment: no, like in the first line of assignment `int a = `...but got the answer from PetSerAl which is at the end more code and less readable than my obvious implmentation with a method call

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I'm not sure what you're asking but I answered how to make it work in my answer above... you put the - in () with it like so (-123)

Comment: the initial desire was that `j = -123` becomes `-321` but the question was with the sign behaviour. that is answered. and the correct LINQ expression is only mentioned by PetSerAl in comments under my Q. Can you mention it in your answer, so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I sort of mention this in my answer now.  Please see the edit and code below my original and let me know if that works.